# How to deserialize an array?

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I'm using the [nlohmann::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library to serialize/deserialize elements in `json`.
Here's how I serialize a `C++` array of double:

```
double mLengths[gMaxNumPoints] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
...
nlohmann::json jsonEnvelope;
jsonEnvelope["lengths"] = envelope.mLengths;
```

Which produce:

```
"lengths":[  
   1.0,
   2.0,
   3.0,
   4.0,
   5.0
]
```

But now, how can I deserialize back to `mLengths`? Tried with:

```
mLengths = jsonData["envelope"]["lengths"];
```

But it says `expression must be a modifiable lvalue`. How can I restore back the array?

Comment: I don't know the library you are using (although I am now looking at it) but the variable you are assigning to is a fixed array. You might want to use a vector which from a cursory look at the lib would behave how you expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have the library at hand, but it should be something like:

```
auto const &array = jsonData["envelope"]["lengths"];

if(!array.is_array() || array.size() != gMaxNumPoints) {
    // Handle error, bail out
}

std::copy(array.begin(), array.end(), mLengths);
```

The `std::copy` dance is necessary because a C-style array is, as its name implies, a very bare-bones container whose specifications has been pretty much copied over from C. As such, it is not assignable (nor copy- or move-constructible either).

Comment: BTW, the library is available [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/tt_LPd)

Comment: I think @markzzz is from a javascript background and so it might be worth explaining why you are using the copy and references rather than just assignment which is what he was trying to do.

Comment: @Caribou fair enough.

Answer (score 6):

It works with vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>                                                

int main() {
    double mLengths[] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
    nlohmann::json j;
    j["lengths"] = mLengths;
    std::cout << j.dump() << "\n";

    std::vector<double> dbs = j["lengths"];
    for (const auto d: dbs)
        std::cout << d << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Deserialization via assignment is not gonna work with C arrays, because you can't properly define a conversion operator for them.